# Why my code doesn't show my TButton's array?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm making a simple hangman game in c++ builder community edition and my game consists of buttons that represents letters and if the letter doesn't appear inside of the word you lose a life, and so on, and so on...
But I'd though that is a little repetitive my code if I make a TButton for every letter in the abcedary. So I decide to make an array of TButton my surprise was when I code everything and any of them appear in my form :c.
If someone can help me a little I'll be so happy haha.

Tgame class...

```
class Tgame : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TText *word;
private:    // User declarations
    TButton* chars[23];
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall Tgame(TComponent* Owner);
    void __fastcall FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action);
};
```

And the constructor implementation...

```
for(int i = 0; i < 23; ++i) {
        this->chars[i] = new TButton(this);
        this->chars[i]->Height = 33;
        this->chars[i]->Width = 49;
        this->chars[i]->Position->X = startX;
        this->chars[i]->Position->Y = startY;
        startX += difX;
        startY += difY;
        this->chars[i]->Opacity = 1;
        this->chars[i]->Visible = true;
        this->chars[i]->Text = "A";
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You construct the `TButton` setting its owner (the component responsible for deleting it).

```
this->chars[i] = new TButton(this);
```

But you don't set its `Parent`, which is the component in which the `TButton` will appear visually. So, add this line:

```
this->chars[i]->Parent = this;
```

Note: The default values for `Opacity` and `Visible` are `1` and `true` so you don't need to set those explicitly.